# Lego Harry Potter Years 1-4 save on iPhone

Tags: ios, lego-harry-potter-years-1-4

After searching around the internet, I came to know that there's no mid-level save in Lego Harry Potter Years 1-4 on the iPhone. Rather the game saves automatically after each level finishes.

When I quit after finding Dudley's presents in the first level and catching all the rats at Diagon Alley, the game still doesn't save. Is the first level not finish yet or is there a bug in my version of the game?

When does the first level actually end?

Answer (score 1):

After playing for sometime I came to know that the game is automatically saved after Gringots quest.

Answer (score 0):

Mine autosaves. Maybe check your settings in options?

Comment: Hey, Shay, welcome to Arqade.  I've removed your question because this space is reserved for answers only.  If you have a different question, feel free to use the Ask Question link at the top of the page.